# Finding spatial derivatives of discrete data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, derivative

Consider I having some points (x,y) in a 2D plane. Each point has a value, i.e. its orientation, so my data matrix looks like F = [x,y,n_x,n_y]. Is there any way to calculate and plot the spatial derivatives of the orientation field in the 2 dimensions?

```
x=rand(100,1);
y=rand(100,1);
orientation_x= rand(100,1);
orientation_y= rand(100,1);
n_x= orientation_x./(orientation_x.^2+orientation_y^2);
n_y= orientation_y./(orientation_x.^2+orientation_y^2);;
```

Comment: Check this out: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html

Comment: I need a better aproximation than gradient

Comment: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/125299-differentiation-in-2d-for-non-uniformly-distributed-data

Comment: You have posted a non-working code (easily fixed, but please make it the people trying to help you as easy as possible), which gives you the input. Anyhow, take a look at the [`gradient`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html) function, that should give you the gradient, obviously. If that's not good enough: explain why it's not good enough (i.e. give sample output as well). You could try interpolating the data to get a denser grid and see if that helps.

Comment: It is not enough because I need a denser grid. I tried to use interpolate but I failed @Adriaan

Comment: @AlbertNestler please red the links Adrian gave you before. "I failed" is not descriptive. You may have failed because a cat unplugged your mouse, and we can not help with that.